# On hovering any elements transform all the elements

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have 3 elements: svg, p and p

**HTML code**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="absolute top-1/4 left-12" width="335.312" height="119.152" viewBox="0 0 335.312 119.152">
    <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" d="M334.1,0H58.861L0,58.861l58.861,58.861H334.1Z" transform="translate(0.707 0.723)" fill="#ed3430" stroke="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>

<p class="absolute text-white top-28 left-24 text-4xl font-extrabold">Text A</p>
<p class="absolute text-white top-52 w-40 font-extrabold italic text-center left-20">Some text...</p>
```

**Css code**

```
svg, p {
    transition: transform 1s;
}

svg:hover, p:hover {
    transform: translate(-30px, 0px);
}
```

When I hover any of these 3 elements I would like to transform all these 3 elements. Currently, if I hover p element then only specific p element transforms leaving other 2 elements unaffected.

**Updated - Video added**

https://www.veed.io/view/b7a90341-0307-4ff1-a871-84639407086b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them all to do the same thing at the same time, you could wrap them in a container instead of trying to iterate through them and get them all to cooperate with each other.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: transform 1s;
  width:max-content;
}

.container:hover {
  transform: translate(-30px, 0px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="absolute top-1/4 left-12" width="335.312" height="119.152" viewBox="0 0 335.312 119.152">
    <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" d="M334.1,0H58.861L0,58.861l58.861,58.861H334.1Z" transform="translate(0.707 0.723)" fill="#ed3430" stroke="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>

  <p class="absolute text-white top-28 left-24 text-4xl font-extrabold">Text A</p>
  <p class="absolute text-white top-52 w-40 font-extrabold italic text-center left-20">Some text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `width:max-content;` to the container :)

Comment: @AStombaugh I am aware of it but then the entire arrow jumps on hover from its location.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I don't follow. You stated you had 3 elements and you want all 3 to transform when hovered on one of them. Can you clarify what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: @AStombaugh added video link.

Comment: @AStombaugh yes it does animate when hovered over any of the element but because all the child elements are absolute and the hover takes place on parent, all the elements animate in different location than expected.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia You will need to go through and style the container to flow with the rest of your HTML. Your post didn't include anything else so I can't know how it's going to interact in the context of your site, I was just addressing your question. And if you're positioning everything with absolute positioning you're asking for trouble. Use flex layouts and layer in your elements properly otherwise you're going to have to take your transition into account on every single element and that's an unnecessary amount of work for you. :)